# What's wrong with nodejs crypto decipher?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, openssl, aes

I have the following encrypted data:

`U2FsdGVkX1+21O5RB08bavFTq7Yq/gChmXrO3f00tvJaT55A5pPvqw0zFVnHSW1o`

The pass to decrypt it is: `password`

(it's the example from [gibberish-aes](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes))

In the command line using openssl:

`echo "U2FsdGVkX1+21O5RB08bavFTq7Yq/gChmXrO3f00tvJaT55A5pPvqw0zFVnHSW1o" | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -k password`

The output is:

`Made with Gibberish\n`

With my NodeJS application:

```
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', "password");
  var dec = decipher.update("U2FsdGVkX1+21O5RB08bavFTq7Yq/gChmXrO3f00tvJaT55A5pPvqw0zFVnHSW1o",
     'base64', 'utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
```

I have the following error `TypeError: DecipherFinal fail` at the `decipher.final` line.

Am I missing something ? Thanks.

Comment: Great question. I found that openssl uses a salt every time, so you need a `-nosalt` switch. With no salt it uses same IV and derived key every time, you can see them providing a `-p` switch. Then you can do `createDecipheriv(data, key, iv)` in the node. But it does not decode the text properly anyway. So I'm stuck too.

Comment: @owlstead I've used **key** and **iv** directly, does this use **PBKDF2**? http://pastebin.com/uhxTRn9T here are my code and results. What is wrong?

Comment: I've looked in the code and it should use the openssl key derivation without a salt. I'm not sure about the IV. I do know that with Java I cannot decrypt the openssl result either. Plot thickens.

Comment: Here are some similar questions and answers: [Decrypting AES256 with node.js returns wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292142/608639), [Nodejs decrypt using crypto error wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111388/608639), [Getting error wrong final block length while decrypting AES256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32038267/608639), [Decrypt file in Node.js encrypted using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44482151/608639), [How to decipher string in node.js which is encrypted in crypto.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28359128/608639).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The encrypted data starts with a 8 byte "magic" indicating that there is a salt (the ASCII encoding of `"Salted__"`). Then the next 8 bytes is the salt. Now the bad news: Node.js does not seem to use the salt for the EVP_BytesToKey method:

```
int key_len = EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, EVP_md5(), NULL,
  (unsigned char*) key_buf, key_buf_len, 1, key, iv);
```

That `NULL` is the salt.

This has been verified using a Java test application (using the right salt) - the result string was returned.

Please leave out the salt using the OpenSSL `-nosalt` switch and try again.

[EXAMPLE]

OpenSSL CLI:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -a -k password
owlstead
Mh5yxIyZH+fSMTkSgkLa5w==
```

NodeJS crypto:

```
var crypto=require('crypto')
var cipher=crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', "password")
var enc = cipher.update("Mh5yxIyZH+fSMTkSgkLa5w==", 'base64', 'utf8')
enc += cipher.final('utf8')
```

---

[LATE EDIT] Note that using secret key derivation with a salt and large work factor may be paramount to security. You'd better use a very unique, high entropy password otherwise your encrypted data may be at risk.

---

[REALLY LATE EDIT] [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.

Comment: encrypted data after Base64 decoding, obviously.

Comment: But I use `-nosalt` as I said before... I know about `Salted__` magic signature in default OpenSSL encoding results. My pastebin example contains `-nosalt`.

Comment: That `U2FsdGVkX1+21O5RB08bavFTq7Yq/gChmXrO3f00tvJaT55A5pPvqw0zFVnHSW1o` string does however contain the salt. You can easily see that it is too large otherwise (even if you don't simply decode the base64 and view the ASCII encoded first 8 bytes).

Comment: Ouch, it really works with `createDecipher()` and `-nosalt`! I haven't tried that combination, only `…iv()` version. You are my and @Sandro Munda hero! :)

Comment: How do you encrypt using node crypto with the -nosalt option?

Comment: i don't understand... you can't use "-nosalt" if you don't have control over the encryption. what if you need to decrypt files already encrypted with a salt?

Comment: You'd have to create your own `EVP_BytesToKey` derivation method in NodeJS, in all probability. Not that hard or risky compared to many other schemes, but still rather specialized work.