# Different encrypted outputs in AES implementations?

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm testing some **AES** implementation in C, got it from [here](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm), compiled it and tested it, encrypting and decrypting works fine for each other.

At [site](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm) it says:

> ***This implementation encrypts 128-bit blocks.***

And also

> ***These programs should be used only for demonstration purposes, because the use of a password as a key gives an effective key length much shorter than the 256-bit key passed to the Rijndael encryption package.***

So, I'm trying to test them and interact with the **openssl**, so if I encrypt anything with the compiled code I got, it can be decrypted with open-ssl or viceversa.

I've tried with `openssl aes-128-cbc -in attack-plan.txt -out message.enc` for encrypting and `openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in message.enc -out plain-text.txt` for decrypting, methods which I actually got from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60712/how-do-i-quickly-encrypt-a-file-with-aes). Also tried with *`128-ecb`* but not getting results.

When I try to decrypt with openssl a file encrypted with the compiled code, and I input the password, it gives me the *bad magic number* error. When I try to decrypt an openssl encrypted file with my compiled code I'm not getting a right decrypted output.

I really need to get *any* implementation of AES in C, and proove it against openssl and getting it working good together.

Comment: it's not really clear exactly what your question is that you want help with.

Comment: I need to know if it's possible to test openssl and the implementation I donwloaded and compiled together

Comment: it looks like the C code is using ECB and does no padding.  so try encrypting a message (a multiple) of 16 bytes followed by 16 bytes of value 16 (pkcs#7 padding).  or use a message (a multiple) of 16 bytes and `--nopad` in openssl (more likely to work).  also, use -ecb-128 or whatever it's called.

Comment: OpenSSL has its own ways of deriving keys from passwords. Owlstead tends to remember the finer details, hopefully he/she will be along shortly to post. In the meantime, try printing the key in the C code and passing that to openssl directly (using the `-K` argument). That will rule out any password shenanigans and would be a useful test.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanJones, you should actually give it as response. It clears out. You might be the *right answer*

Comment: It might be a solution. Did you try what I suggested and did it work?

Comment: @DuncanJones Although I'm along now, I've got little time to convert the proprietary OpenSSL key derivation method to C. Note that since OpenSSL is in C you could just copy `EVP_BytesToKey`. If you just enter a password instead of using `-K [hexkey]` then it certainly *will* be used. Oh, and I'm male :P

Comment: Oh, and the OpenSSL routines add/expect a proprietary header to store the salt value and some magics too if the key derivation method is being used.

Comment: So, @owlstead, in conclusion, it's quite *impossible* to make openssl and my code work together?

Comment: Of course not. The OpenSSL code is available and key derivations functions are not *that* hard to implement; it's just that you have to create a compatible library. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219499/whats-wrong-with-nodejs-crypto-decipher) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-file-in-java-with-openssl-with-aes).

Comment: Thanks, I just really don't have time to implement anything. My *task* is to get any C implemented code and study it, then testing it with openssl. I was thinking about downloading the code from openssl and compiling it then ...

Comment: Going for the -K hexkey as Duncan proposed would be the quickest way.